# Unable to connect to Redshift from psql?

Tags: amazon-web-services, connection, amazon-redshift, psql

I am using the following command to log into my redshift cluster:

```
psql -h my-cluster.ho46wegweg423.ap-southeast-1.redshift.amazonaws.com -p 5439 -U username
```

This prompts me to enter *password for username* and I get the following error:

```
psql: FATAL: database "username" does not exist
```

I am able to log into the cluster from SQLWorkbench/J but not from command line.

Comment: Which version of `psql` are you using? Preferably, it should be version 8.0.2, to match the PostgreSQL version that is used by Amazon Redshift.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify database name "-d my_database" after the hostname.

Comment: @nacliasmsi - No, that is actually not necessary

Comment: yes it is. redshift needs to know which database you are trying to connect. that is why you are getting that error. it thinks that your username is the database name coz the database argument is required.

Comment: Database name is required AFAIK. For SQLWorkbench you maybe copied the JDBC or ODBC URL from the properties tab? Those contain the database name. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-from-psql.html.